# Croppic: how to change behavior of image dragging functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day. There is a popular application http://github.com/sconsult/croppic. Project demo: http://www.croppic.net. I am trying to use variant `Preload` (in demo). If I drag image with rotation `angle = 0` or `180`, I can reach all areas of image (and see it in crop area).

If I drag image with rotation angle `<>` `90` (`80`, `120`, etc.) - I have unreachable areas, which I can't drag in crop area with such rotation angle. But I need ability to drag all parts of resized and/or rotated image to the crop area. Can you help me to defeat this restriction or tell, where is it - `java` `initDrag` / `onImgDrag`, `cropContainer`, `imgWrapper`? I can't understand, where I can find restrictions/parameters/conditions, which define this behavior.

**Illustration:**
[image]
Or you can repeat my example on Croppic demo page.

Comment: If in croppic.js (github.com/sconsult/croppic/blob/master/croppic.js) I comment lines 498-512, I can freely drag and move image in crop area, but this "solution" provides wrong coordinates for crop. Is there easy way to calculate true coordinates with this conditions?

Comment: For all who have the same problems with Croppic I can recommend use this module: it can rotate, resize and crop images and have some useful settings. https://github.com/alisey/image-crop It have a very special "markers" functionality, but you can turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the code in the `touchmove` handler (Line 476).

The image is bound to the container and in the source the image position is reset to fit thouse boundaries every time you drag (starts at Line 489).

Comment: Thank you for help! This is what I am looking for.